# how to refer to the nth element in a jquery object

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery selector to select a bunch of divs. I want to be able to ask for the 8th element of the resulting collection. How can I do this?

Comment: `[7]`, `.eq(7)`, or `.get(7)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `nth` element you'd do the following:

```
$(selector)[n-1];
```

If you need it as a jQuery object, you can get it from the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method:

```
$(selector).eq(n-1);
```

For example, the 1st element, would be

```
$(selector)[0]
```

*Thanks Jason P - again*

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: `$(selector)[n];` or in your case: `$(selector)[7]` Or even the use of [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) `$("div:eq(7)")` if you are selecting the eighth `<div>` element.